# Exporting geodatabase file from ArcMap 10.0 to SQL Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, export, sql-server

I have a GIS feature class of lines in a file geodatabase that I want to export directly to SQL Server. I only have ArcMap 10.0 to view this file and I can't see how it is possible using that. Usually, I export to shapefile and then upload from there but this is over 2Gb so I want to do it directly.

I already have the database set up in SQL Server, I just want to export directly from ArcMap and create a new table in SQL.

Is this possible?

I have tried using the Feature Class to Feature Class tool, and create a new Database Connection. If I test the connection, it works fine, however when i save the new Database Connection it has a little red cross next to it and still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve? I have a hard time understanding what is your problem.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov - I just want to export a table of lines from a file geodatabase to SQL Server?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm should work

Comment: What is "a spatial table of lines in a file geodatabase"? Is it just a table, or is it a GIS feature class?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov - Can you create database connections in Arc 10.0 though, it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @DanC - Apologies, it is a GIS feature class.

Comment: @al_sweets, yes, ArcMap 10.0 will let you connect to an enterprise database provided that the system and compatibility requirements are met http://help.arcgis.com/en/systemrequirements/index.html#/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Database_Requirements/015100000070000000/

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov - When trying to export to the Database Connection, i get this error now "Neither the isolation level nor a strengthening of it is supported."

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 isn't going to connect to any database released this decade. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact versions of all software (including service packs)

Comment: Note that the answer to 99% of "Is this possible?" questions is "Of course, with a bit of work" (the remainder are "a lot of work" and "an awful lot of work").

Comment: Assuming the SQL Server database is a geodatabase? Either a remote ArcGIS Enterprise SDE Geodatabase or a local [SQL Server Express Database Server SDE Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/database-servers/setup-database-server.htm)?  You simply create a database server connection in Catalog and copy and paste items from FGDB to SDE.

Answer (score 0):

As said, there is no one-click tool to achieve this within ArcGIS or ArcPro standard packages.

GDAL and its OGR2OGR tool can be used to transfer shapefiles to MS SQL Server relatively painlessly and without writing code.

So export to a shapefile, then execute the following from a shell script:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=localhost;database=<database name>;trusted_connection=yes;" "my_exported_shape_file.shp" -progress
```

The ogr2ogr documention documents many additional arguments.

In the spirit of the question, a quick but dirty way of building this into a tool in ArcGIS would be to have a python script export to a shapefile, then generate and execute an OGR2OGR shell call.

After that there would be many options of mediating data transfer through many python packages, like pysql, SQLAlchemy and geopandas, or working natively with WKT formats to transfer spatial data.